# A couple questions about partially ordered sets

Tags: combinatorics

Is a set of all integers or the set of positive integers a partially ordered set? With respect to the relation's "divides"?

And is there a partially ordered set that isn't a lattice? Or are all partially ordered sets lattices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the divisibility relation partially orders $\Bbb Z^+$. It does not partially order $\Bbb Z$, because on $\Bbb Z$ it isn’t antisymmetric: for instance, $1\mid-1$ and $-1\mid 1$, but $1\ne -1$.

A partially ordered set need not be a lattice: the relation of equality is a partial order on any set, and $\langle X,=\rangle$ is not a lattice if $X$ has more than one element.